# How to resolve error when determining if Date is between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
data = {'Date': ['2022-01-02', '2022-01-13','2022-02-12','2022-02-15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I created the Dataframe and then check what the dtype for the new entries are

```
df['Date']
```

The dtype shows up as dtype: datetime64[ns]
So now I tried to create dummy variables to determine if something was in between two sets of dates:

```
df['2/11-2/13  DV']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (2022-02-13 <= x <= 2022-02-13) else 0)
```

But it keeps return the same error:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'
Any help on how to resolve this error would be appreciated.

Comment: your date "2022-02-13" gets evaluated as a an integer as 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["2/11-2/13  DV"] = (
    (df["Date"] >= "2022-02-11") & (df["Date"] <= "2022-02-23")
).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date  2/11-2/13  DV
0  2022-01-02              0
1  2022-01-13              0
2  2022-02-12              1
3  2022-02-15              1
```